# do a lookup with 1 specific value from array within aggregate

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

So i'm converting some .findOne and .findById to one nested aggregate. And I then need to do a lookup by a value in a array "that is not" the id of the user sending the request (which is also in this array).

The schema looks like this for what i'm aggregating of

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    members: {
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    itemId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    firstMessageSent: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    lastActive: {
        type: Number
    }
})
```

The members property has the id for the 2 users included in a conversation, and I would then need to do a lookup with the id that is not equal to the user sending the request. I can't figure out how to do this with a let/pipeline, as I can't use $not. Anyone who know what could be a solution? my current setup to get this working looks like this, and I would try to make it more optimized with a aggregation

```
router.get('/:sub', utility.authenticate, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.user.sub !== req.params.sub) res.status(403).json('not authenticated');
    const conversations = [];
    await Conversation.find({
        members: {$in: [req.user.sub] }
    }).then( async (_conversations) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < _conversations.length; i++) {
            let conversation = {}
            let _conversation = _conversations[i];
            const otherMemberId = _conversation.members.find(member => member != req.user.sub);
            await User.findOne({sub: otherMemberId}).then((user) => {
                let _user = {};
                _user.avatar = user.avatar;
                _user.sub = user.sub;
                _user.username = user.username;
                _user.name = user.name;
                _user.user_since = user.meta.user_since;
                conversation.user = _user;
            })
            await Item.findById(_conversation.itemId).then((item) => {
                let _item = {}
                _item._id = item._id;
                _item.name = item.name;
                _item.assetId = item.assetId;
                _item.exterior = item.exterior;
                _item.image = item.image_url;
                _item.inspect = item.inspect_link;
                conversation.item = _item;
            })

            conversation._id = _conversation._id;
            conversation.members = _conversation.members;
            conversation.lastActive = _conversation.lastActive ? _conversation.lastActive : 0;

            conversations.push(conversation);
        }

        res.status(200).json(conversations.sort((a, b) => b.lastActive - a.lastActive));
    }).catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
})
```